# Is it safe to run Ruby HTTP server from the user who owns codebase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httpserver, application-server

For example, in PHP-based apps it's recommended to run PHP-FPM from a user different from the user who owns codebase so if anyone hacks your app from the web won't be able to write anything to a codebase (except public assets directory). It seems like ruby apps designed to run HTTP servers (or application/rake servers) like Unicorn and Puma from the same user. Puma (the default rails server) doesn't even have config entries for specifying a user/group.

**UPDATE**

What I expect to do with a ruby app (the same I do with PHP-FPM) is to run `sudo unicorn` or `sudo puma` from a default user (codebase owner) and specify a user/group (like `www-data`) in config so the HTTP server will run the master process from root and child processes from `www-data`. Puma has no such settings and I haven't found any related issues in puma's repo. This made me think that maybe it's a common thing in Ruby ecosystem to run it like that. I still tried to run latest rails app (5.2.1) with unicorn but faced another issue: rails has a dependency on bootsnap gem and when you run `sudo unicorn -c config.rb` it creates `tmp/cache/bootsnap-*` directories as root (in master process) which breaks everything because child processes running from `www-data` won't have access to it. That made me consider again that maybe I'm doing something wrong and it's ok to run ruby apps from codebase-owner although I see no arguments how it's different from running PHP-FPM.

Comment: You run your production server as your deploying username which is configured to have access to only the deployment directories, also set the environment variable from your deployment script(capistrano) so that your connection details aren't visible to anyone except the application.

Comment: Rails apps typically have a dedicated web server. It's unusual to have one web server run multiple Rails apps (which seems to be quite common in PHP land).

Comment: Rails apps are usually deployed with an additional server layer such as nginx or apache passenger. Not Puma directly. Thats where you would handle the config.

Comment: @Stefan I don't get how having another server in front changes anything, the user that runs application server still has full access to the codebase

Comment: @Surya deployment directories? Do you mean like codebase?

Comment: @max what config? The application server still has full access to codebase, how another http server upfront can change it?

Comment: You can change which user is running the server via nginx or passenger. I don't get why you assume that the user has write privileges (well except /public if you want to do user uploads).

Comment: @max my original question is about a user who owns codebase. Not sure how any configuration on the server (e.g. nginx) that proxies requests to application server can change the fact that I run puma from the codebase owner. I would love to run puma with sudo and specify user/group (e.g. www-data) for child processes like I do this with FPM but it just does not have these settings

Comment: @max another example – unicorn has settings for user/group so I can run it with sudo and specify user/group (e.g. www-data) BUT if you run a rails app (latest stable version) it has a dependency on bootsnap gem that creates tmp/cache/bootsnap-* directories as root (in master process) which basically means it's not designed to run like that